# Select text and remove shape from another layer

Tags: inkscape, text, selections

I have two layers:

- layer 2 – text “hello”
- layer 1 – black square

I would like to select an outline of the text, change my highlighted layer to layer 1, then cut/delete that shape from the black layer.

I will then be able to delete/make-invisible the text layer and what remains will be a black box with a shape of the text “hello” cut out of it.

In Photoshop [Mac] (which I no longer have access to), this was simple:

1. Cmd-click the text layer
2. Select the black box layer
3. Cut pixels

What is the equivalent in Inkscape?

Answer (score 1):

As Inkscape does not have shaped selections as these mostly make sense in pixel graphics. Instead you manipulate the shape of an object through another shape:

1. *Duplicate* the text.
2. Add the square to the selection (click it holding <kbd>⇧</kbd>).
3. *Path → Difference.*

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for me. When I make the text layer invisible, the box does not have the shape of the text cut out of it.

Comment: It works fine for me. Did you by any chance lock a layer? Also, all of this does not need layers to work, so maybe try without them. Finally, try applying *Stroke to Path* to everything before doing anything. This should not be needed, but just to be on the safe side.